# Android Instant App, Why It doesn't work in feature module using activity transform animation XML?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

You can try this sample just for invalid animation in changing activities: https://github.com/SwayChen/InstantAppTest.

I have tag a `TODO` on both `onCreate()` & `onBackPressed()` [ app module works fine, the feature-a not ]

The following is some short descriptions.

`overridePendingTransition` work fine in app/library module.

But now it can't work in feature module, it just have flicker animation when start Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.none);
}
```

The following is the two animation XML:

**R.anim.none:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**R.anim.slide_in_right:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="320"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Comment: @ SwayChen, `overridePendingTransition` when used with Feature Module (and project run as an Android Instant App) results in similar behavior at my end too. I would suggest you to submit your project to Google's [Issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). They will take a look at it. (also, please share the link to that filed bug here)

Comment: ok, I have post a issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70650534

Comment: Thank you, we can hope for a response soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news!** The engineers have fixed the issue, `overridePendingTransition` animation now **works with Instant Apps on O+ devices**.

The custom transition animation is not supported in AIA on pre-O devices and there are currently no plans to support this in near future.

Please report [AIA Team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70650534) if you encounter any issues.

Comment: Thanks for mention :)

But we have abandoned Instant App without no bad app growth..